# How to use OpenCV function CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(...) with mask?

Tags: opencv

How to use OpenCV C++ function CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(...) with mask?
I know, the  object can turn up only in certain non-rectangular part of an image, and want to save computations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a plain way to use it with mask.

However, you can try to mask the input image, such that areas outside your ROI will be zeroed. When the classifier will test rectangles in the masked area, it will probably fall in very early stages, thus reducing running time.

This approach, however, has the risk of having misdetections in the boundary of your ROI, where you create new patterns.

Comment: Thank you, user3801908, so far I planned to apply the method exactly you have suggested. I also thought of CascadeClassifier::runAt(...), but couldn't see how to  get FeatureEvaluator parameter from pretrained cascade.